# Synchronize web database to local database

Tags: c#, synchronization

I am building an ecommerce website, and I have a local inventory(database) and an online database with which I want to synchronize my inventory at a regular time interval in C#. Can someone tell me what am i looking at here ? like what kind of resource should I be looking at in order to do so ?

Answer (score 1):

You are using C# to do the synchronization, right?

I suggest that you first track changes on your local database (Every insert/Update/Delete will be tracked.) you can use your custom tracking mechanism or use [SQL server Change Data Capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

The second step will be to get those changes on your local database based on an interval of time, then update your online database.

Comment: okay thanks I will look into SQL server change data capture !

Answer (score 0):

Create a windows scheduler to update your remote inventory details in your

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL Data Compare for this purpose. [Here].(http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/) Crack version is also available on internet. It generates the scripts for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use araxis merge tool & Compare two databases.